# Get all tables which has primary key with data type uniqueidentifier in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to write a query that will return all tables name which has Primary key column with data type uniqueidentifier.

*Can anyone please help me.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sql server [object catalog views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx):

```
select 
     IndexName  = i.name
   , SchemaName = schema_Name(t.schema_id)
   , TableName  = t.Name
   , ColumnName = c.Name 
   , TypeName   = type_name(c.user_type_id)
from sys.tables t
  inner join sys.indexes as i on
            t.object_id = i.object_id
        and i.is_primary_key = 1
  inner join sys.index_columns as ic on 
        i.object_id = ic.object_id
    and i.index_id = ic.index_id 
  inner join sys.columns as c on 
        c.column_id = ic.column_id
    and c.object_id = ic.object_id 
    and type_name(c.user_type_id) = 'uniqueidentifier'
```

rextester link: http://rextester.com/SAL18997

Comment: Great. thanks a lot!! will accept ur answer after 2mins. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Col.Column_Name , tab.TABLE_NAME ,DATA_TYPE 
 from 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab join 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col   on col.CONSTRAINT_NAME =        Tab.CONSTRAINT_NAME
   join   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS columns on columns.COLUMN_NAME =   Col.COLUMN_NAME and col.TABLE_NAME =columns.TABLE_NAME
 WHERE 
   Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
   AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
  AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND columns.DATA_TYPE = 'uniqueidentifier'
```